# Creating a linked list of 2 strings C++

Tags: c++, string, linked-list

I'm trying to teach myself linked lists by making a linked list using 2 strings based on which string is first in the alphabet. Then, the function will return a pointed to the alphabetically sorted list of 2 strings. I don't know why, but my following code isn't doing what I'm expecting it to do. I would really appreciate it if someone could take a look at my code and let me know why this isn't working.

```
struct Node{
    string val;
    Node* next;
};

Node* makePairList (string s1, string s2) {
    Node* h = NULL;
    Node* n = NULL;
    Node* t = NULL;

    if(s1 > s2)
    {
        n = new Node();
        n->val = s1;
        t=n;
        h=n;

        n= new Node();
        n -> val = s2;
        n-> next = NULL;
        t -> next = n;
        t=n;
    }
    else
    {
        n = new Node();
        n->val = s2;
        t=n;
        h=n;

        n= new Node();
        n -> val = s1;
        n->next = NULL;
        t -> next = n;
        t=n;
    }

    return h;
}
```

Comment: How do you know "this isn't working"?

Comment: Have given it a go and found that `makePairList("abc","def");` does work in the sense that is creates a linked-list with two nodes with value being "def" in the first node and "abc" in the second.
Is the "swapping" of "abc" and "def" the problem?

Comment: I would suggest to reorganize you function since your actions in both cases almost identical. First create two nodes structure ``h = new Node; t = new Node; h->next = t; t->next = NULL;`` and then depending on ``if`` condition set ``val`` field for both nodes. This will simplify and reduce your code. ``if( s1 < s2 ) {h->val = s1; t->val = s2;} else {h->val = s2; t->val = s1;} ``

Comment: A common trick is to call `makePairList(s2, s1)` when the arguments are initially in the "wrong" order. Or call `std::swap(s1,s2)`.

Comment: This function, as I could analyze it, creates two dynamic objects of type Node, one with the value with one of the strings, the other of the value of the other string, where the first element points by `next`to the second one, and the `val` of the first element is less than the `val` in the second element. The first node object is returned as a pointer.

If this function was *supposed to do something else*, please explain.